# Export older c4d files into fbx/obj

Tags: export, cinema4d

newbie to Cinema 4D here and never worked with it before! I have a couple of .c4d files in the zip file linked below that were created in an older version (R11.5 or older) of Cinema 4D, and hence I can't really access it. I was wondering if there are any kind souls out there with a 2019 release or earlier that could possibly export this file as obj or fbx (with the material/texture assignments preserved if possible) so I can import it and work with it in Blender (which I have access to and am familiar with). Would be very very thankful!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14LZlhmhXthdhvXXeRdPCbMguhZnSyhNT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. “I was wondering if there are any kind souls out there with a 2019 release or earlier that could possibly export this file as…” The purpose of GDSE is not to do your work for you, nor to solicit unpaid work. This question should be closed.